# Is there a proper term for this type of "connected widgets" paradigm?

Tags: gui-design

Is there a proper term for this type of user interface? I'm looking to research libraries to use for a project, but "connected widgets gui" is so generic, it just brings up results for GUI widgets in general.

I recall seeing the terms "wires" and "ports" used in various places that I've seen this paradigm used before, but again these terms are so generic, and trying to research it is difficult, because all I get are results talking about networking cables etc...

[image: Connected Widgets?]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Depending on the fidelity, I'd call it a wireflow or a prototype. Not sure if there's a more generic/broadened term for that. Interested in finding out.

Comment: @lzquierdo: What do you mean "fidelity"?

Comment: A series of wireframes vs a series of UI designs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These types of interfaces are commonly referred to as **Node Graphs** or **Node Editors**. They are typically used for **Visual Programming**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node_graph_architecture

Answer (score 0):

In Axure, this is called "snapshot" where you combine mockups with a traditional flow diagram. Maybe something like "snapshot flow"?

Answer (score 0):

This seems very similar to databases models. The terms that I would search for are graph visualization/ schema diagram design templates.